# how to change my selected tab text color in android

Tags: android

I am new to android ,how to change my selected tab text color 
my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "MEN-Clothing", "WOMEN", "KIDS" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
   // getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);



    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }





    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}




@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

}
how to change my selected tab text color in android any one help me ,my present text color is ash code color when i am selecting any tab my text color should be white

here my style.xml code

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>




<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
  <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/tabStyle</item>

<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
 <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#029C7A</item>

</style>
<style name="ActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">       
<item name="android:textColor">#CFCFC4</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

#FFFFFF

false
        #029C7A

Answer (score 0):

you can call these overwrite method in your MainActivity and change text there

```
 @Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Change color here!!
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
tab.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Hope this may help your cause,
if not message me.

Comment: tab.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white);        where i need to create color.white

Comment: when i am using that method i got bellow error                                                     The method getColor(Context, int) is undefined for the type ContextCompat

Comment: i have created color.xml in values folder which is inside res folder. or you can just give android defult colour, i think that was R.android.white   and if  you getting error you can use MainActivity.this or MainActivity.class in place of Content @SwamyVeera

Comment: or you can try this inside onTabSelected                         

      {tabs[position].setTabTextColor(android.R.color.white)} ; 

  which may also help, just try that out .

Answer (score 0):

You can

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

// on tab selected

viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

//Here You can deal with your tab

}

Comment: tab.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white);

Comment: ok, than try this way get the selected page index and than use that index in onTabSelected(){tabs[position].setTabTextColor(..)}